# Why does the Tool Help Library offer 2 versions of same functions/structures?

Tags: winapi

I've noticed that the [Tool Help Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/tool-help-reference) offers some functions and structures with 2 versions: normal and ending with `W`. For example: [Process32First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-process32first) and [Process32FirstW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-process32firstw). Since their documentation is identical, I wonder what are the differences between those two?

Comment: `WCHAR` vs `CHAR`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings#unicode-and-ansi-functions

Comment: ^ Foo = mapped to either FooA or FooW depending on project build type ASCII or Unicode.  FooA = always ASCII, FooW = always Unicode. Win32 / WinAPI has hundreds of functions that follow this pattern.

Comment: Thanks everybody for swift replies. One more thing: I've looked up the header of the Tool Help Library and I couldn't find the ASCII version of those functions. I'm just curious why there are none.

Comment: ASCII is there to support old code, some of it 20+ years old.  Most modern apps are written with unicode build settings.  Microsoft only writes W versions of some functions now.

Answer (score 0):

The W and A versions stand for "wide" and "ANSI".  In the past they made different functions, structures and types for both ANSI and unicode strings.  For the purpose of this answer, unicode is widechar which is 2 bytes per character and ANSI is 1 byte per character (but it's actually more complicated than that).  By supplying both types, the developer can use whichever he wants but the standard today is to use unicode.

If you look at the ToolHelp32 header file it does include both A and W versions of the structures and functions.  If you're not finding them, you're not looking hard enough, do an explicit search for the identifiers and you will find them.  If you're just doing "view definition" you will find the #ifdef macros.  If you still can't find them, change your character set in your Visual Studio project and check again.

Due to wide char arrays being twice the size, structure alignment will be incorrect if you do not use the correct types.  Let the macros resolve them for you, by setting the correct character set and using PROCESSENTRY32 instead of indicating A or W, this is the preferred method.  Some APIs you are better off using the ANSI version to be honest but that is something you will learn with experience and have to make your own decision.

[Here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) is an excellent article on the topic of character sets / encoding